# Redistributing BSD-licensed software?

Tags: licensing, gpl, bsd-license

Is it acceptable to distribute unmodified BSD-licensed software (pyglet) with GPL-licensed software I created? The BSD allows for sale of modified software, I know, but does it allow re-licensing of unmodified? Seems to defeat the purpose of having a license at all.

Comment: Discussion here http://lwn.net/Articles/247872/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to relicense as the BSD license is compatible with the GPL: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses